# Extensions in vs code don't load

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I just want to install dart and flutter here but as you can see it doesn't load and when I click to install it opens a market in Google Chrome and I managed to install just flutter manually but it doesn't want to install dart and it looks weird like this :

[image: like that]

Comment: Your wifi signal looks to be barely existent. This could be an internet connection issue.

Comment: But it works just fine in my browser

Comment: This looks like a network connectivity issue. If you click Help -> Toggle Devloper Tools in VS Code, you might be able to see the failure messages in the console/network tab.